# Unable to locate source of spam member registrations in Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine

Been receiving a lot of spam member registrations through our Expression Engine based website.

The site uses the Profile:Edit module to handle registrations.

I have tried many anti-spam methods to no avail -- captcha, recaptcha, honeepot, honeypots etc. you name it!

It seems like the spam bot is some how getting around my registration form and submitting entries some other way.

Answer (score 1):

After browsing the server's raw access logs I could see the spammer was actually posting registrations submissions to `/member/register` which is a member registration page automatically created by Expression Engine -- I had no idea.

If you go to `Control Panel -> Members -> Preferences` you can edit the value of the `Profile Triggering Word` -- change this to stop spammers, or set it to `#` to prevent access to these automated pages all-together.

> **Profile Triggering Word** --
>   When this word is encountered your URL it will display your member profile area. The word you choose cannot be the name of an existing template group.